# htaccess URL rewrite - Get parameter after second to last and last hyphen

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting

I need to get var1 and var2 from the URL bellow using .htaccess URL rewrite.

**URL:**

```
<a href="tmp/image-file-name-var1-var2.jpg">link</a>
```

**HTACCESS:**

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^tmp/([^\.]+)(here i need help)\.(png|jpg|gif)$    image.php?image=$1.$4&size=$2&position=$3 [NC,L]
```

**RESULT SHOULD BE:**

```
image.php?image=image-file-name.jpg&size=var1&position=var2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this code:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^tmp/(.+)-([^-]+)-([^.]+)\.(png|jpe?g|gif)$ index.php?image=$1.$4&size=$2&position=$3 [L,QSA,NC]
```